# Direct traffic from LAN interface into VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, loopback

I have created a loopback network interface (by a software tool). Now I want to direct internet traffic through this interface. Note that I only can access internet via a VPN .
Now I do not know how I can direct interface traffic between VPN and my virtual interface.(There is no bridge option for accomplish it in Windows 7)
[image]
**EDIT :**
I think that I should add a routing item into routing table of my Windows 7 but in `ROUTE ADD` command there is no way to specify **incoming** traffic, only provides specification for **outcoming** traffic
Or
I need a 3rd party software which gets traffic from my interface and send them through VPN

**Routing table:**
[image]

Comment: Please post the output of ipconfig and your routing table.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I've added some more info, please see edit

Comment: Set a route to your internal IP address through your interface with a lower metric so it gets chosen as the shortest path.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger Internet is only accessible via my VPN not my loopback interface so I must direct internet traffic through VPN, and It's done as you can see in the route table ( direct to VPN has lowest metric, 11)

Comment: If you have VMWare or similar program there is an OS that was created where you can create virtual networks etc. So you can use this OS to create a bridge if you will. Take a look at "Vyatta"